# DAG: Configuration refresh failed with the following error: the metadata failed

Tags: windows-server-2019, dag, exchange-2019

I have two mailbox servers in exchange 2019 and I have installed DAG . I have set the static IP address for Dag and the process is ok ( Active and Passive Databases ) . But after failing one server and moving the Databases to other server , I get an error in server manager on both of my server and also I can not ping the DAG IP , it is time out .

The problem is :

**DAG : Configuration refresh failed with the following error: The metadata failed to be retrieved from the server, due to the following error: WinRM cannot complete the operation. Verify that the specified computer name is valid, that the computer is accessible over the network, and that a firewall exception for the WinRM service is enabled and allows access from this computer. By default, the WinRM firewall exception for public profiles limits access to remote computers within the same local subnet.**

Please help me , if everyone have this experience.

Thanks

P.H

Comment: Refer to the reply in https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/2321414-dag-configuration-refresh-failed-with-the-following-error-the-metadata-failed?page=1#entry-9196418